# Amazon S3 secure URL at the bucket level

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to be able to serve URLs to client that are "signed" and so, are only relevant to 24 hours (for example).
However, I don't want to call S3 for every URL generated:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.new(bucket, name).url_for(:read, :secure => true, :expires => expires_in).to_s
```

Instead, I want to generate the URL by myself (I have the file name and the bucket link, I can build it myself).

However, I want to sign the url at the bucket level (say, once a day for all the files in a given bucket). is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a pre-signed URL, that is done completely locally. You could do it "by yourself", but it is much easier to use the SDK, and there would be no practical diferences. See that there is no "sign" action on the [S3 API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html).

However, you can not sign at the "bucket level", as signature is checked per-object. I believe signing a whole bucket would not be feasible.

Comment: The line I extracted above is an a actual call to amazon as to get the signed token. It is not local as far as I can see.

Comment: You can monitor your network or check the source (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/b54a5561180c7eaae14e2a8ac440ce4a48c8de8f/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb), this method call is resolved locally and does not invoke the remote service.

Comment: My god. I had a "bucket.blank?" in my code, which is what triggered the call to AWS - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/b54a5561180c7eaae14e2a8ac440ce4a48c8de8f/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb#L252 I didn't even consider this... thanks.

Comment: Accepted this answer as this one is correcting my wrong assumption that invoking a url_for(secure: true) is a network call.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I do not have ruby code for this only Java...

But you will not be able to get a presigned url for the whole bucket, only each file.

Here is the function I created. This will print everything for you. Does the process make sense?

```
private static URI GetURL(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary) throws URISyntaxException {
    return amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(
            new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3ObjectSummary.getBucketName(), s3ObjectSummary.getKey())
            .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .withExpiration(GetExperation())).toURI();
}

public static void run(String accessKey, String secretKey, String bucketName) {

    AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
    amazonS3Client.listObjects(bucketName)
            .getObjectSummaries()
            .stream()
            .forEach(s3ObjectSummary
                    -> System.out.println(GetURL(amazonS3Client, s3ObjectSummary).toString()));
}
```